# LoadRunner concatenating correlated values

Tags: correlation, loadrunner

I have captured loadrunner correlation variable "Date" as below using ORD=ALL:

```
vuser_init.c(165): Notify: Saving Parameter "Date_1 = 101".
vuser_init.c(165): Notify: Saving Parameter "Date_2 = 102".
vuser_init.c(165): Notify: Saving Parameter "Date_3 = 103".
vuser_init.c(165): Notify: Saving Parameter "Date_4 = 104".
...
```

Now I want to substitute these values in the subsequent request as in comma separated format as the following:

```
101, 102, 103, 104...
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Storing the number of matches in count integer variable as Date_count will store all the matches
count = atoi(lr_eval_string("{Date_count}"));

// Storing all the values in commaSep variable
for (i=1; i<=count; i++)
{
    if(i == count)
    {
        sprintf(value,"{Date_%d}",i);
        strcat(commaSep,value);
    }
    else
    {
        sprintf(value,"{Date_%d}",i);
        strcat(commaSep,value);
        strcat(commaSep,",");
    }
} 

// Printing the result in Output console, after this you can use this variable wherever you want in your script
lr_output_message("Comma Separated value is = %s,lr_eval_string(commaSep));
```

Answer (score 0):

C variable + loop  to limit of your array + sprintf()

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of functions for manipulating LR Params, and the ones you need are
    char * lr_paramarr_idx( const char * paramArrayName, unsigned int index);
    int lr_paramarr_len( const char * paramArrayName);

I've quickly made a function you can use for this:

```
/**
* ArrayToString( char *ResultParam, char *ArrayParam, char *Delimiter)
*
* @param ResultParam    The resulting LoadRunner variable to contain result
* @param ArrayParam     The Array param where the elements are
* @param Delimiter      Delimiter to use between elements in list
*
*/
int ArrayToString( char *ResultParam, char *ArrayParam, char *Delimiter)
{
  int idx,count;
  char buf[1024];

  // Create a tmp buffer with "{ResultParam}"
  sprintf(buf,"{%s}",ResultParam);

  // Get the Count of params
  count = lr_paramarr_len("Date");

  // Clear the variable
  lr_save_string("",ResultParam); 

  // Add 1st variable
    lr_param_sprintf(ResultParam, "%s",lr_paramarr_idx(ArrayParam, 1));

    // Loop all variables, adding them to "ConcattedDates", starting at idx=2
    for (idx=2; idx<=count; idx++) {
      lr_param_sprintf (ResultParam, "%s%s%s", 
         lr_eval_string(buf), 
         Delimiter,
         lr_paramarr_idx(ArrayParam, idx)
       );
    }

    // Return the length of the Concatenated buffer. 0=Nothing in buffer
    return strlen(lr_eval_string(buf));
}
```

**Example Usage**

```
// Take "Date" array param, output to "DateConcat" param
ArrayToString("DateConcat", "Date", ",");

// Debug output
lr_error_message( "DateConcat='%s'", lr_eval_string("{DateConcat}") );
```

In your case the resulting `DateConcat` string would be `101,102,103,104`

Answer (score 0):

In the code posted by K.Sandell I don't see concatenation of the values of a parameter array; I see the value of ResultParam being *replaced* rather than concatenated. My goal was to output all the values of the array in a single line (which I collected to use in another script). The following code, using strcat, got the job done for me:

```
// Loop all variables, adding them to "stringOfValues"
for (idx=1; idx<=TotalNumberOfMatches; idx++) 
{      
  strcat(stringOfValues,  lr_paramarr_idx("arrParameter", idx));
  strcat(stringOfValues, Delimiter);

  lr_output_message("ResultParam =%s", stringOfValues);         

}
```

// Final Output will print concatenated values

lr_output_message("ResultParam =%s", stringOfValues);

---

Sample Output (a string of values in a line separated by the delimiter):

ResultParam =BU21, BU25, BU28, BU44, BU100

Incidentally, the normal, better way to pass parameter values would be to pass the parameter array itself to the next script or action where you want to use it (not convert it to strings). But in my case I wanted to run the above code on the LoadRunner controller, in a multithreaded manner, and collect the output for use in a report. I then used Windows findstr /s /C:"ResultParam" *.log to search through the controller's output to find these values. This approach required that all the data be on a single line in the controller log file.